# Why Is String Theory Called A Theory

Tags: string-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laws of Atomic Theory - how is this possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/laws-of-atomic-theory-how-is-this-possible)

Generally in science, a theory is effectively a fact.  The **theory** of evolution is not a guess, or a hypothesis.  It's currently understood to be a fact, backed up by evidence from numerous scientific fields spanning many decades.

String **theory** on the other hand seems much more contentious, much less settled in the scientific community.  Why isn't it called the string hypothesis?

Answer (score 7):

These terms are not used consistently, nor in a way consistent with the way people who talk about science interpret them. For example, the thing called the "standard model" is not really a model anymore (except for the Higgs sector), but an excellent theory, perhaps even a fact of nature, but it is still called the "standard model", not the "standard fact".

An open-ended program you can publish new fundamental papers about is always called a "theory". A "model" is something that was perfectly and precisely well defined in the original paper, like the Weinberg-Salam model. A "law" is a simple mathematical relation that comes either from experiment or theory. A "hypothesis" is a tentative guess, and turns into a theory when you can start writing papers about it. A "principle" is a hypothesis that you really believe in.

These terms are more publishing terms than philosophical terms, and don't give them too much respect.